# Codeigniter controllers/models structure with helpers

Tags: php, codeigniter, models, controllers, helper

Quick Codeigniter question really... I built an eCommerce site with a lot of repetitive `menus` and `submenus` etc. It was my first Codeigniter project, so while it all works, it's not structured brilliantly...

My Controllers are quite `bulky` and slow to load. I'm now looking at trying to `structure` my Contollers and Models - I'm guessing I can probably put most of it into helpers and have them autoloaded for ease - but I'm a bit unsure where to start and what can go where; I'm looking for some advice.

Controller:

```
<?php

class Seixweb_live_brands extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Seixweb_live_model');
    }

    public function product_lookup_by_id($str1) {
        if ($this->uri->segment(3)) {
            $filter = $this->uri->segment(3);
        } else {
            $filter = 1;
        }
        $config = array(
            'base_url' => base_url() . '/brands/' . $str1 . '/' . $filter . '/',
            'total_rows' => $this->Seixweb_live_model->brands_num_rows(),
            'per_page' => 30,
            'uri_segment' => 4
        );
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $query = $this->Seixweb_live_model->brands_row();
        $data = array(
            'title' => $query->sw_brand . ' | Fragrance, Skin Care & Shaving Brands for Men | eMale Grooming',
            'description' => $query->sw_brand,
            'keywords' => $query->sw_brand,
            'heading' => $query->sw_brand,
            'total_rows' => $config['total_rows'],
            'filter_url' => base_url() . 'brands/' . $str1 . '/',
            'header1_result' => $this->Seixweb_live_model->submenu1_result(),
            'header2_result' => $this->Seixweb_live_model->submenu2_result(),
            'header3_result' => $this->Seixweb_live_model->submenu3_result(),
            'header4_result' => $this->Seixweb_live_model->submenu4_result(),
            'header5_result' => $this->Seixweb_live_model->submenu5_result(),
            'tpl_result' => $this->Seixweb_live_model->menu_result(),
            'view_result' => $this->Seixweb_live_model->brands_result()
        );
        $this->load->view('seixweb_live_header_view', $data);
        $this->template->load_seixweb_live('seixweb_live_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('seixweb_live_footer_view', $data);
    }

}
```

Model:

```
<?php

class Seixweb_live_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function brands_result() {
        $str1 = $this->uri->segment(2);
        if ($this->uri->segment(3) == 2) {
            $filter = 'a.search_price ASC';
        } elseif ($this->uri->segment(3) == 3) {
            $filter = 'a.search_price DESC';
        } elseif ($this->uri->segment(3) == 4) {
            $filter = 'b.timestamp DESC';
        } elseif ($this->uri->segment(3) == 5) {
            $filter = 'discount DESC';
        } else {
            $filter = 'b.sw_brand ASC, b.sw_subbrand ASC, b.sw_product ASC, b.sw_size ASC, b.sw_unit ASC';
        }
    }
}
```

etc. etc. etc.

Thanks!

Comment: u r using autoload want to know how can u use it in controller???

Comment: No, I haven't put anything into helpers yet. I want some advice on what (from above code examples) could potentially be moved to helpers - which I can then autoload, to make my coding more stream-lined etc.

Comment: You want crate helper file to use more time and for flexible?

Comment: Yes, that's right.